# React - routing when there is a hash inside of a routing parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

So I have an application where you can navigate between cars. All cars have an ID, some cars have an ID with a hash, for example, 'test#car#1'. That seems to ruin the navigation, as it doesnt work when an ID contains a # symbol.

I have created [**an example in code sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v4-demo-forked-qokkl?file=/App.js) where there's a # inside of a route, and the navigation to that specific route doesnt work.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar">
          <ul className="nav">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/category">Category</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pro#ducts">Products</Link> // the problematic route
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/admin">Admin area</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/category" component={Category} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} />
          <Route path="/pro#ducts" component={Products} /> // the problematic route
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way to work around this? To be able to use # inside of the IDs of the cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your CodeSandbox and this is the fixed

```
<li>
   <Link to={`/${encodeURIComponent("pro#ducts")}`}>Products</Link>
</li>

// Some other code
<Route path={`/${encodeURIComponent("pro#ducts")}`} component={Products} />
```

The error happened because `encodeURIComponent` encode the `/` which lead to the confusion of route directing. Move `/` outside fix the problem. Although I'm not sure why you would use route name like that